# How to open localhost when you listen to port 80 in node.js?

Tags: node.js, localhost

I am currently starting out in **node.js** and I want to open my **server.js** file in localhost. What is the URL directory path for that, as I have noticed you don´t need the foldername where the file is located in as in Apache.

But I am not sure. Otherwise my directory is the following **Desktop/node-projects/exercise-node-mongo/server.js**

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_get_started.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is not explicitly made for running web applications, you need to create the web server using your own code in Node.js

A popular framework for running a website on Node.js is Express which can be installed simply by opening command prompt in the folder you have stored `server.js` in and run the following steps:

1. Run the command `npm install express` to install express
2. Edit `server.js` in your favourite editing program(notepad)
3. Insert the following code

   ```
   const express = require('express')
   const app = express()
   const port = 3000

   app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
   app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
   ```
4. Run the app by running `node server.js` from the command prompt
5. Open `localhost:3000` in your browser and you should see the text `Hello World!` appear

You should look at the guides for express to learn more on how it all works https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html